# Failure occurs when trying to connect my registered device to the IoT Foundation on BlueMix

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, ibm-cloud, iot

I can successfully communicate with IoT in quickstart, but after I modify the code to include specific credentials for my registered device,  I get an "unsuccessful connection". I have been using the [online recipes](https://developer.ibm.com/iot/) and tutorials for connecting my IOT device to Bluemix.

I can get past the first part of the recipe and successfully communicate with IoT Foundation in Bluemix using the quickstart connection, so that part works for me.  But I encounter an error and my connection fails when I try to do the connection as a registered device.

Trying to connect an arduino device, I followed this tutorial: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-bluemix-arduino-iot1/index.html

Please let me know if you have a suggestion as to what I should check to determine why the connection fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When connecting with Quickstart to Internet of Things Foundation there is no authentication required.  A client must simply use a valid client ID and access the permitted topic space.

When connecting a registered device, or with an API key, authentication is required.  Its important to use SSL to protect the password in this case.  As with Quickstart, the client ID must also be correct and reflect the registered device being connected.  The client ID must be the following format:

`d:org_id:device_type:device_id`

where

- `org_id` is the organization ID provided when you signed up and displayed when you log into https://internetofthings.ibmcloud.com or as seen in your Bluemix IoTF service credentials (as provided in your `VCAP_SERVICES` properties).
- `device_type` is the type of the device specified when registering the device.
- `device_id` is the ID of the device specified when registering the device.

The username must be `use-token-auth` and the password must be that provided after the device was registered.  Please check these details are correct in the sketch you are using.

For more information please see [MQTT Connectivity for Devices](https://docs.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/messaging/devices.html).  If you still have problems, please supply your organization ID, device type, and device ID so we can check your details.  Please *DO NOT* supply the device password as this intended to be kept secret.